# Sql Server 2008 Query to put null for non existing values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are two tables {`PERSONS, CONTACTS`}

I want the following result form these two tables

```
PersonID | Name
1        |  A
2        |  B
3        |  C
4        |  D
5        |  E
```

Table `Contacts`:

```
ContactID | PersonID | Type | Contact 
1         | 1        |  p   | 051-001
2         | 1        |  e   | A@    
3         | 2        |  p   | 051-002
4         | 2        |  e   | B@
5         | 3        |  p   | 051-003
6         | 4        |  p   | 051-004
7         | 4        |  e   | D@
```

Desired result output:

```
Name | Contact
A    |  051-001
B    |  051-002
C    |  051-003
D    |  051-004
E    |  NULL
```

Please look at the Fiddle for this problem
[SQLfiddle for Problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/793f2/4)

Comment: Post the query what you tried...

Comment: `select [Name], [Contact] from Persons p left join Contacts c on p.PersonID = c.PersonID`?
I guess what you are looking for is **LEFT JOIN**

You may like to google for "join types" to get more information.

Comment: No, I don't want to do it using LEFT JOIN. What my requirement is to do it using sub-query....

Comment: Then I think it would be a good idea to write this in the question.

Comment: The bad idea is a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nor sure why you dont want a left join but this is using a sub query.

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    (SELECT Contact 
     From Contacts c 
     WHERE c.Type = 'p' And c.PersonId = p.PersonID) 
    As Contact
FROM 
    PERSONS p
```

Comment: @danihp the requirement was for a subquery and not using any left joins, not sure how you would do that without a correlated subquery.  However I fully understand there would be a drop in performance.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is. Do you need a Left Join to take all rows from `Persons`. Also, in `on` condition, you can filter for `Type = 'c'`

```
SELECT P.Name, C.Contact
FROM PERSONS  P
left outer join CONTACTS C
   on C.Type = 'p' and
      P.PersonId = C.PersonId
order by P.Name
```

Comment: I'll skip pointing out the general equivalence of joins vs subqueries and just upvote you because, well that's what the client wanted and you did it :)

Comment: @cmsjr, before post my answer I have started to wrote a comment in your answer. But writing comment I have seen that my approach differs significantly fron yours and I have post my own answer. Thanks about your honest review!

Answer (score 4):

```
Select p.Name, c.Contact
from Persons p
left join Contacts c
on p.PersonId = c.Personid
Where Type = 'p' or c.Contact is null 
Order by p.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Another unusual method ;) It's not the best `regexp`. But it does the job for your case.

```
select distinct p.name,  c.contact
from 
persons p
left join
contacts c
on p.personid = c.personid
where c.contact is null or
c.contact like '[0-9]%'
;
```

Results:

```
NAME    CONTACT
A       051-001
B       051-002
C       051-003
D       051-004
E       (null)
```

*** [SQLFIDDLE Reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/827ed/1)**

Comment: @Zeb-Ur-Rehman take a look at this. Please comment once you try out.